# Вопрос по дженерикам и боксинге

Tags: c#, c#-11.0

Я хочу "оптимизировать" стандартный метод HasFlag структуры Enum, но в виде дженерика.

вот что получилось:

```
public static bool HasAnyFlag<T>(this T value, T flag) where T : IBinaryInteger<T>
{
    return (value & flag) != T.Zero; //просто 0 тут нельзя поставить
}

public static bool HasFlag<T>(this T value, T flag) where T : IBinaryInteger<T>
{
    return (value & flag) == flag;
}
```

Теперь о моих догадках:

1. where T : IBinaryInteger по моему мнению не должно вызывать boxing типа Т так как эта запись является статической проверкой на этапе компиляции
2. Однако в методе HasAnyFlag выражение

return (value & flag) != T.Zero;

наверное вызывает проблему, так как параметр Zero является членом интерфейса IBinaryInteger (или его базовых),а также операторы & и != являются членами этих интерфейсов. А раз так - то должна происходит упаковка

В итоге, все эти "крутые новшевства" NET 7 - можно засунуть?
Почему не сделать бы до путя? Или я не вкурил как этим пользоваться?

Любые другие попытки обойти это всеравно приводят к использованию методов, которые являются членами класса Object или принимают Object в качестве аргумента.

Неужели нельзя ничего сделать?

**П.С. В итоге enum не реализуют эти интерфейсы. И это не работает(( Но с обычными базовыми структурами похоже нет никакого боксинга, потому как методы являются виртуальными и переопределяются где-то в структуре, а может это оптимизированно для базовых типов, не знаю. Но этих методов в базовых типах я не нашел** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: ClrHeapAllocationAnalyzer не обнаруживает в данном коде боксинга.

Comment: @iikuzmychov Спасибо за статью, но на самом деле я тут не занимаюсь ничем лишним. Нам всем было заявлено "ох как теперь жизнь наладится" после того как появился NET7 и его новые дженерики. И если твои ожидания рушатся - возникает вопрос: Зачем все эти "нововведения", если они упрощают работу лишь сайто-кодерам которые ложили болт на производительность, на боксинги, на 10разовое копирование данных при неправильном использовании LINQ.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0315?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0315)

В итоге он даже не позволяет это использовать

Comment: В итоге, нет ничего лучше чем просто самому прописывать побитовые операции там где это нужно. Потому что enum создали, а базу под них не подвезли от слова совсем

Comment: То есть вы взяли инструмент, не предназначенный для вашей задачи, и начали ныть, что сайто-кодеры плохие. Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Перечисления (Enum) в дотнете не реализуют интерфейс `IBinaryInteger`. Поэтому странно, как вообще мог возникнуть этот вопрос. Посмотрите в документации, какие интерфейсы они реализуют, от этого и отталкивайтесь.

Comment: В .NET7 не появились _новые дженерики_. Появились _новые интерфейсы_, которые действительно очень полезны и эффективны в некоторых случаях.

Comment: Книги Рихтера хороши, но они по .NET Framework. И поэтому частично устарели. В .NET Core было сделано очень много оптимизаций, в том числе и при работе с перечислениями и дженериками. Читайте статьи Тауба (Stephen Toub) на devblogs.microsoft.com.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150762/discussion-between-alexander-petrov-and-artem).

Comment: [Slow Enum.HasFlag performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/performance-insights-enum-hasflag?view=vs-2022)